# Exception thrown: read access violation. **pGroup** was nullptr

Tags: c++, visual-studio, active-directory, adsi

I want to check whether a current user is belongs to a particular group in active directory or not using c++ code. I'm using ADSI documentation code, below I add the code which i'm getting an error. **Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation.
**pGroup** was nullptr.**  This is the error i'm getting. Can anyone please help me to solve this error. Thanks in Advance.

```
//#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinBase.h>
#include <Iads.h>
#include <Adshlp.h>
#include <atlbase.h>


int main()
{
IADsGroup* pGroup = NULL;
HRESULT hr = S_OK;

std::string path = "WinNT://10.0.14.74/Administrators";
std::wstring spath = std::wstring(path.begin(), path.end());
LPCWSTR lpszPath = spath.c_str();

LPCWSTR adsPath = lpszPath;
BSTR bstr = NULL;
::CoInitialize(NULL);
hr = ADsGetObject(adsPath, IID_IADs, (void**)&pGroup);
//std::cout << hr;
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    std::cout << hr;
}

hr = pGroup->get_Description(&bstr);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    std::cout << hr;
}

printf("Description: %S\n", bstr);
SysFreeString(bstr);

VARIANT_BOOL inG = false;
hr = pGroup->IsMember(CComBSTR("WinNT://Microsoft/SecUser"), &inG);

if (inG)
{
    printf("already in the group.\n");
}
else
{
    printf("User not in that group.\n");
}
CoUninitialize();

return 0;
}
```

In this line **hr = pGroup->IsMember(CComBSTR("WinNT://Microsoft/SecUser"), &inG);** I don't know what this Microsoft/SecUser means?  Can anyone please help me to solve this error. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `if (FAILED(hr)) {std::cout << hr;}` you probably should exit the program or return from this function if it failed instead of continuing and using the invalid pointer.

Comment: Also, the CoInitialize and CoUninitialize calls should be in a RAII wrapper class, where CoUninitialize would be called on the destructor of the class, regardless of the reason being returned from the function.  Otherwise your code would be littered with CoUninitialize() calls at every single exit point.

Comment: If you got this code from some documentation, then you will need to change the username and the group name to match what you're looking for. The documentation may tell you exactly what you need to change.

Comment: @GabrielLuci - This is the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nf-iads-iadsgroup-ismember.  In that there are not clearly mentioned that's why i'm not sure what to change. I have doubt only in that two WinNT lines. So can you please guide me to get the code ?

Comment: That page says that the code "adds the 'jeffsmith' user to the 'Administrators' group on the 'Fabrikam' domain". Those are the three things you need to change: the user and group you want to look for, and your domain.

Comment: Have you checked that your domain and user are correct?